# Algebraic data types in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to figure out how to use algebraic data types in Kotlin, so I'm trying to implement a basic BinaryTree type the following way.

```
sealed class Tree<T>{
  class Node<T>(val left: Tree<T>, val right: Tree<T>): Tree<T>()
  class Leaf<T>(val value: T): Tree<T>()
}
```

This is all fine, and lets me construct the following tree:

```
val myTree1: Tree<Int> = Node(Leaf(4), Leaf(2))
```

However I would like to have an "Empty" type as well, so I can express the following:

```
val myTree1: Tree<Int> = Node(Node(Leaf(4), Leaf(3)), Empty)
```

I tried the following:

```
sealed class Tree<T>{
  class Node<T>(val left: Tree<T>, val right: Tree<T>): Tree<T>()
  class Leaf<T>(val value: T): Tree<T>()
  object Empty: Tree()
}
```

Though I get the error that Type argument is expected at object Empty: Tree(), which is actually quite logical.

I tried

```
object Empty: Tree<T>()
```

But it resulted in "Unresolved reference: T". As a last resort, I tried writing

```
object Empty<T>: Tree<T>()
```

But the compiler says "Type parameters are not allowed for objects"

Is there a way to express this in Kotlin? Empty should be a singleton, this is why it should be an object. By making it a class, it solves the compiler problems, but then I have to put parentheses after it like that => Empty(). Also, it creates unnecessary objects, while it really should be a singleton value.

I'd appreciate any help on this issue. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First you need to make `T` an `out` parameter. Then you can use `Nothing` as a type argument for `Empty`.

```
sealed class Tree<out T>{
  class Node<T>(val left: Tree<T>, val right: Tree<T>): Tree<T>()
  class Leaf<T>(val value: T): Tree<T>()
  object Empty: Tree<Nothing>()
}
```

`Nothing` is a special type in Kotlin, which cannot have an instance and is a subtype of all other types. So I would say it's opposite to `Any` in Kotlin type hierarchy.

Comment: It works, thank you! 
Also, I learned something about Nothing as well. :)

Comment: you don't need `out` here - it works without it. Please clarify that

Comment: @voddan if you remove `out` it will become impossible to create a `Node` with a `Leaf` and the `Empty`.

Comment: What if I need T to be Comparable (I am thinking of BSTs)? Declaring `sealed class Tree<out T :  Comparable<T>> {..}` gives the error "Kotlin: Type parameter T is declared as 'out' but occurs in 'in' position in type Comparable<T>"

Comment: @David Soroko: Have you found any working solution for the Comparable<T> example?

Comment: Not a satisfactory one. One approach is to give up on having a singleton `object Empty`, remove `out` and  have `class Empty<T> : Tree<T>()` . Then you either accept multiple instances of `Empty` or manage a single, type specific instance manually.