# Can a covariant type parameter be in an input position in the constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, kotlin, covariance

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36753782/303685), [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170842/michael) suggests that the generic type parameter be made co-variant in order to allow the creation of an empty node.

I get that the generic type parameter is in all output positions since all the properties of the `Tree<T>` and its sub-types are read-only (`val`'s).

But it *does* have the type parameter in an input position in the constructor.

I thought that that code wouldn't work in C# so I tried it out and, to my surprise, it worked just fine.

```
// See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753579/algebraic-data-types-in-kotlin
// Short url: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36753782/303685
interface ITree<out T> { }

class Tree<T>: ITree<T> { }

sealed class Node<T> : Tree<T>
{
  private readonly T _left;
  private readonly T _right;

  public Node(T left, T right)
  {
    _left = left;
    _right = right;
   }

   public T Left { get { return _left; } }
   public T Right { get { return _right; } }
 }

class Program
{
  static void CovarianceTest1()
  {
     ITree<object> tree = new Node<string>("Hello", "World!");
  }
}
```

I realize now that in doing this exercise, I learnt something new about variance.

**So, my first question is:**

*Are co-variant type parameters allowed in input positions in constructors? In what other places are type parameters allowed to disregard their variance qualifiers?*

Another thing I learnt about variance is that the variant generic type parameter may not even appear in the variant interface declaration as seen in the example below.

```
interface ITree<out T> { }
```

You'll see that the `ITree<out T>` interface does not have `T` in either input or output positions. This also came as a shock to me.

**My second question is:**

*And the other question I have is, what is the C# equivalent of the `Nothing` type in Kotlin? The answer says that `Nothing` is the most sub-type that cannot further be derived. It is the exact opposite of `Any` (or the most base type in other languages).*

To emulate that code in C#, it didn't make sense to have this:

```
class Empty : Tree<null> { }
```

Because that's just illegal C# code and `null` also doesn't seem analogous to `Nothing`.

So, I had to fake a dummy like so to imitate the `Empty` class declaration.

```
sealed class Dummy { }

sealed class Empty : Tree<Dummy>
{
  private static Empty _empty = null;
  private static object syncLock = new object();
  private Empty() { }
  public Empty Instance
  {
    get
    {
    if (_empty == null)
    {
      lock (syncLock)
      {
        if (_empty == null)
        {
          _empty = new Empty();
         }
        }
       }

       return _empty;
      }
   }
}
```

**My third and final question is:**

*Therefore, my final question is, is there a place that contains an exhaustive list of all the types available in Kotlin along with their descriptions? Because even though the [Basic Types page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html) lists most of the common ones, it seems not to be an exhaustive list. The types not listed there are all sprinkled over [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/). Like in the instance above, they just appear with a mention on a page here or there.*

Comment: Your question is way too broad and conflates a number of different topics. On the first, regarding the constructor, classes aren't variant, interfaces are. And a constructor isn't part of an interface. You can violate variance in the class itself however you like; it doesn't matter because the only place you can _use_ the variance is when treating the type via the interface.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you. Do you suggest I break down the question and post as multiple questions?

Comment: Yes, I do think that would be better. Though, I predict the answer to your #2 question is "you can't do that" (because you can't), and your #3 question is just plain off-topic (it's asking for a recommendation for some external resource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All types that are shipped with Kotlin are described in its [API reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html), in particular the `kotlin` package:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/