# How to create and GADT type with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, functional-programming, gadt

What I would like to declare in Kotlin is an operation with different possible results with what is called GADT (Generalized algebraic data type) using a declaration like this:

```kotlin
sealed interface Response<T> {
    data object Pending: Response<T>
    data class Ok(val result: T): Response<T>
    data class Error(val reason: String): Response<T>
}
```

But sadly the declared type `T` is not propagated to the internal declarations.

This is something rather normal in other functional programming languages like Scala, Haskell or Elm but it looks that for Kotlin this requires a different syntax or maybe is even impossible in Kotlin.

Someone knows a possible answer?

Comment: How about just declare the type parameter again? `data class Ok<T>(val result: T): Response<T>`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36753579/5133585).

Comment: Yes !! ... using `Nothing` makes the trick ... thank you very much, you've saved the day !!